# Align text with input and div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want the div which I use as border to be vertically centered. But it looks like the div is going upwards

[image: div going upward]

```html
<label> Application </label> <input type="text" style="width:10%; bottom:20px;">
<div style="width:1px; height:20px; background-color:grey;display: inline-block"></div> <label> Iteration </label> <input type="text" style="width:10%">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: middle;` to align vertically.

```html
<label> Application </label> <input type="text"  style="width:10%; bottom:20px;">  <div style="width:1px; height:20px; background-color:grey;display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;"></div> <label> Iteration </label>  <input type="text" style="width:10%">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vertical-align: middle`.

But better practice to draw the separator line using borders- see sample snippet below.

Check and let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
.left-border {
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<label>Application</label>
<input type="text" style="width:10%; bottom:20px;">
<label class="left-border">Iteration</label>
<input type="text" style="width:10%">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<label> Application </label> <input type="text"  style="width:10%; bottom:20px;">      
<div style="width:1px; height:20px; background-color:grey;margin:-5px 0px;display: inline-block"></div> 
<label> Iteration </label>  <input type="text" style="width:10%">
```

or

```
 <div style="width:1px; height:20px; background-color:grey;vertical-align:middle;display: inline-block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<label> Application </label> <input type="text"  style="width:10%; bottom:20px;">&nbsp;<div style="width:1px; height:20px; background-color:grey;display: inline-block; vertical-align:bottom;"></div>&nbsp;<label>Iteration</label>  <input type="text" style="width:10%">
```